# displaying url link using jinja

Tags: google-app-engine, url, browser, jinja2

Hi I am using jinja2 with google app engine and wondering if it is possible to display the url link in the browser after jinja renders the page.

For example, if my browser goes to a url, www.test.com/login,  my server script will receive the GET request and send login.html via jinja back to the browser.  However, the link on my  browser will still display only www.test.com/login and not www.test.com/login/login.html

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the file that you use for rendering and the current url path that your handler handles.
The content is passes thru a stream and you can put what ever you want in the stream, it can be content rendered from a template or any data that you will write to stream.

you can write a handler that will receive that template name as a parameter and render it, this will give you the url with the template file name.

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is handled through the request handlers and your app.yaml file.  So if you map the request to www.test.com/login.html that is what is matched vs a request matched at www.test.com/login.

So your question really doesn't have anything to do with Jinja but your request handlers.

For example

app.yaml

```
application: your_app
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
default_expiration: "1d"
threadsafe: True

- url: /login.html
  static_files: static/html/login.html
  upload: static/html/login.html
  secure: never

- url: /login
  script: main.app
```

main.py

```
import webapp2
from controllers.LoginHandler import LoginHandler

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/login', LoginHandler)
], debug=True)
```

In the above example I show 2 different routes.  One static route for /login.html, and a second generated route for /login.  If you don't want .html then don't match that route.

A note about matching, Search Engines treat http vs https differently so it is good to use the `secure: never/always/optional` for your routes to make certain it is bookmarked the same.  Also a trailing / and .html are different than the naked route.  It is very useful to enforce your routes for search indexing reasons.